# Como usar una variable de un formulario de c# en otro

Tags: c#

Podrían explicar como puedo usar una variable declarada en un formulario se podría usar en otro.

Comment: Has intentado algo para lograrlo?

Comment: Mejor no haz eso asi, sino usar un property en un static class.

Comment: Intente inicializarlo en la segunda form , llamando a la primera, pero no funciona.

Comment: Muestra algo del código que has intentando hasta el momento, por favor. Tiene el formulario desde el que quieres utilizar la variable una referencia al formulario donde ésta ha sido declarada?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes crear una clase estática que de acceso a todas las variables que quieres compartir entre formularios:

```
public static class ClaseCompartida
{
    public static string ValorConfig;
    public static int MaxNum;
    // otras variables estáticas
}
```

Y desde los formularios las llamas como una variables estática común y corriente:

```
public void MetodoForm1()
{
    ClaseCompartida.ValorConfig = datoTextBox.Text;
}

public void MetodoForm2()
{
    MessageBox.Show(ClaseCompartida.MaxNum.ToString());
}
```

Las clases estáticas solo pueden tener miembros estáticos, y son muy útiles en casos como este.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo intentaré

Comment: No me sale... :(

Comment: Pon el código que has escrito en tu pregunta original, para que podamos verlo.

Answer (score 0):

**Variable entre formularios**

Podrías pasarla como un parámetro dentro del constructor de tu nuevo formulario y de esta forma puedes asignarla a una variable del mismo tipo y trabajar con la nueva variable sin afectar la primera.

Ejemplo en tu formulario donde declaras tu variable:

```
//Variable que deseas pasar
ObjEjemplo variable = new ObjEjemplo();
//Llamas el constructor que recibe la variable
Formulario2 form2 = new Formulario2(variable);
form2.show();
```

En tu segundo formulario recibes la variable y la signas si así lo deseas

```
    //Constructor principal
    public Formulario2()
    {
    //Utilizado por defecto. No recibe nada
    }
    //Constructor que recibe la variable
    public Formulario2(ObjEjemplo _variable)
    {
    //Haces lo que gustes con la variable preferentemente la asignas.
    }
```

Recuerda que puedes hacer la sobrecarga de métodos en los constructores para crear más constructores con diferentes parámetros si así lo deseas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo directamente así. Gracias por preguntarlo, lo vi claramente al ir programando el ejemplo.

Crea los dos forms en el IDE. *Form1* se crea por defecto al crear una nueva solución. Luego le das con el boton derecho al proyecto (en el explorador de soluciones) y :

*Agregar >> WindowForms*

Creas entonces el segundo formulario con el nombre por defecto : *Form2*.
Entonces le creas los botones y demás grupos de controles que necesites en cada Form. Y acomodas el siguiente codigo y uso de la variable del ejemplo a tu programa.

Este es Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace usarVarEnOtroForm
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        internal static string variableCompartida;


public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
            Form2.Activate();
            Form2.Show();
        }

}
```

Este es Form2.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace usarVarEnOtroForm
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        internal void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Size = new Size(500, 250);
            this.Location = new Point(300,250);
        }


        private void getVar_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.variableCompartida = richTextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```